# Fragments reacting to Activity's event

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have Activity with ViewPager that contains several Fragments. I am also using drop-down navigation in actionbar

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

To this navigation bar I have some callbacks:

```
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mNavigationCallback);
```

My problem is that changing option in navigation list should affect all Fragments inside ViewPager.

How should I do it to be compliant with good OO principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have your fragments implement an interface like this:

```
public Interface NavigationListener {
    public void onNavigationChanged(args...)
}
```

And then just call that method on each fragment in mNavigationCallback.